# Email address based routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So the basic concept is, i want an app that is routed as such :

```
http://host/subscriptions/my@email.com/new # create a new subscription
http://host/subscriptions/my@email.com/7/  # view the subscription with id 7
```

Now, the typical way to navigate i found, was using ID's, and i've seen around SO and other blogs how to use Usernames, but havn't found any on email address, and to me, i wouldn't think they'd act differently but they seem to as i cannot get the same result.

Now, i've tried multiple things, and i'm closest to my result now, now i just need SO to help out!

In my routes file -

```
routes.rb:
----------
SubscriptionCenter::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :subscriptions, :constraints => { :id => /[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/ }
  resources :subscribers
  resources :batches
  resources :batch_runs
  ...
```

As you can see here - I am treating my email address as an ID.  I'm using an email address regular expression, which works fine, however - to me this is dirty.

My model looks like

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :batch_id, :subscriber_id
  ...
```

Batch ID representing the batch to subscribe to, and subscriber_id representing another model that i have -

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :email_address
  ...
```

So to my question -

In my controllers, I am using

```
params[:id]
```

To fetch the email address.

### Questions:

1. Can i substitute params[:id] with something more appropriate, like params[:email_address]?  (params[:email_address] hasn't worked for me)
2. I've seen namespaces in routes, and i understand the concept, but how do i use it with something dynamic like an email?  I don't use a namespace, instead, i use several matches like `match 'subscriptions/:id/new', :to => 'subscription#new'`
3. Assume the following url: `http://host/subscriptions/my@email.com/7/`.  if i were to remain using `params[:id]` for the email, how would I fetch the 7 on the end? 7 representing the batch_id column

Comment: FYI you can use [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) to tell Rails how to make URLs instead of using the default `id`. I'd also be curious to know if the URL will screw up in some way because of the @ symbol. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @MrDanA So far the @ symbol hasn't been screwing up. right now, i can access /subscriptions/my@email.com and it will use subscription#show.   i've done research on the to_param, and if the email field were in the Subscription model, that'd be ok, but it's in the Subscriber model.  Would it help to see the schematic? i can edit my post

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at [friendly_id](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1209730) gem? I think that will solve your problem

Comment: So my issue here is - take a look at my `Subscriber` model. this would work if i went to `/subscribers/my@email.com` but i don't want that. how can i get it to go to `/subscriptions/my@email.com`.  Subscription doesn't hold the email address.